# Finding friends with specific job title

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find all my friends with a specific job title, and no matter what I put in filter, it always return nothing
FQL query:
select name, work.position from user where work and uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2 = me()) 
and work.position.id= 103141116410872